# htaccess is not working on centos 6 vps hosting

Tags: .htaccess

I have two websites on my vps hosting one Codeigniter and the other one is normal php . they both has htaccess , the problem is Codeigniter's htaccess is working and the htaccess of the other website is not.
this is htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index?$ index.php
RewriteRule ^today.html?$ today.php
RewriteRule ^tomorrow.html?$ tomorrow.php
RewriteRule ^contact.html?$ contact.php
RewriteRule ^tag/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+).html tag.php?tag=$1
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: htaccess file is not working no matter what i wrote on it its not working . i test it with "Deny from all"  but i get the home page